# Explanation regarding continuity in piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $ \begin{equation}
     f(x) = \begin{cases}
          e^{-1/x}, & x > 0,\\
          0, &  x \le 0
          \end{cases} \end{equation}$

I have proven that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x \in R\setminus {0}$, and in order to prove that it is continuous at $x=0$, consider  $(x_{n}) \in \mathbb R_{+}$ as well as $(y_{n}) \in \mathbb R_{-}$

For a sequence $x_{n} \to 0, n \to \infty$, we have $f(x_{n})=e^{-1/x_{n}}$. My intuition would be to just say

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_{n}) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {1}{e^\frac{-1}{x_{n}}}$=$\frac{1} {e^\lim {n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{-1}{x_{n}}}}=0$.  But would this not be 'illegal' as taking the limit into the equation already constitutes it being continuous at $0$.   Isn't that exactly what I am attempting to prove?

I'm struggling to understand this nuance. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you mean $e^{-1/x}$?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can justify that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}f(x)=f(0)$.

But $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}f(x)=0=f(0)$ is clear.

Now we need only that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}f(x)=0$.

For the sequential characterisation for the right limit, one may assume $x_{n}>0$ and $x_{n}\rightarrow 0$, then the rest goes through.

Having assume $x_{n}>0$ and $x_{n}\rightarrow 0$, the only thing to deal with is to justify that $e^{-1/x_{n}}\rightarrow 0$.

This is by the spirit of composition. One may use the fact that $e^{u}\rightarrow 0$ as $u\rightarrow-\infty$. Given $\epsilon>0$, then there is some $M<0$ such that for all $u$ with $u<M$, then $e^{u}<\epsilon$.

Concentrating with this $-1/M>0$, since $x_{n}\rightarrow 0$, there exists some $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies that $x_{n}<-1/M$, keeping in mind that $x_{n}>0$, then we are allowed to flip over to get $x_{n}^{-1}>-M$, and hence $-x_{n}^{-1}<M$.

Such an $-x_{n}^{-1}$ can be a candidate for such a $u$ just mentioned, so $e^{-1/x_{n}}<\epsilon$, this shows that $e^{-1/x_{n}}\rightarrow 0$, as expected.

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {1}{e^\frac1{x_{n}}}$=$\frac{1} {e^\lim {n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{1}{x_{n}}}}=0$ by go through?

Comment: Yes it is, because we are dealing with right limit.

Comment: So before that we would have had to state the $e^{\frac{1}{x}}$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ so that we can go through?

Comment: Details added. Actually there is no continuity of $e^{1/x}$ to be assumed, you may take a look.

Comment: One only needs to assume the fact that $e^{u}\rightarrow 0$ as $u\rightarrow-\infty$, but this is no continuity.

Comment: Thanks, we cannot assume continuity on $(0,\infty)$ of $e^{\frac{1}{-x}}$ despite the fact that it is just the composition of two continuous functions $e^{x}$ and $\frac {1}{-x}$ on $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: The point is, the continuity of $e^{-1/x}$ on $(0,\infty)$ does not help. Because the centred issue is at $x=0$, which the domain of $e^{-1/x}$ has excluded. Also for the function $-1/x$, the point $x=0$ is excluded. So the continuity does not really help. In other words, you cannot even say the continuity of $e^{-1/x}$ at $x=0$.

Comment: I thought that this continuity enabled the 'go through' action (for lack of a better word, only know the german word) for the limit, as $(x_{n})_{n} \in \mathbb R_{+}$ strictly and it is continuous on this part. I am a bit confused how else I would reason it in a first year real analysis course test, other than with the above.

Comment: For the domain of the function $f$ in question, since it includes the point $x=0$, you can reason about its continuity of $f$ at $x=0$. But when you write $e^{-1/x}$ on $(0,\infty)$, essentially you have created another function with domain $(0,\infty)$ and you can only talk about the continuities of $f$ at the points in $(0,\infty)$ which the zero does not belong, so discourse about the continuity of this new function at the point $x=0$ does not even make sense.

Comment: Another trick in dealing with the continuity of the $f$ in question is to look at the left and right limit if they coincide with $f(0)$. For the right limit, see, it is just a limit, you are trying to compute the limit, and much less continuity issue is taken account in computing the limit because the right limit is so nasty that the point $0$ cannot be inserted in $1/x$, so if one tries to use the continuity at $0$ to do with the right limit, surely it fails.

Answer (score 1):

What you've done is not illegal. You did not take the limit of *your* function, you've taken the limit of the function $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$, which happens to coincide with your function on $(0, \infty)$. Your function and $e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ have the same values, therefore they have the same limit when $x\to 0^{-}$.

(Of course, you now need to prove that $\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}e^{-\frac{1}{x}}=0$, which is more-or-less done in your question; I am not sure if your write-up is rigorous enough, but this is another matter...)

Answer (score 0):

**just a hint**

If $x_n>0$ and $x_n\to 0$ then

$$\frac {1}{x_n}\to +\infty $$
and

$$e^{\frac {-1}{x_n}}\to e^{-\infty}=0$$

thus $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f (x)=0=f (0) .$$

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, but I'm arguing about something else. How can I allow the limit into the equation like this $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {1}{e^\frac1{x_{n}}}$=$\frac{1} {e^\lim {n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{1}{x_{n}}}}=0$ since I don't know whether the it is continuous at 0, surely I am only able to perform the operation I mentioned above only when it is continuous at 0.